# Meaning of Undefined reference error

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

Undefined reference error refers to missing declaration or the definition or both?

Compiler: GCC on Linux

Comment: Without the actual error it's hard to guess, but probably it's a missing definition.

Comment: Since compiler/linker errors are tool specific, to get a precise answer you should tell us what compiler you are using.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Well, in my case it was a missing definition. but I wish to know if the declaration is missing isn't the error same?

Comment: @PéterTörök GCC on Linux

Comment: If the declaration is missing, the error usually says something like "XXX was not declared in this scope".

Comment: @jrok You are correct, I just verified it. Post that as an answer, I'll select it.

Comment: @jrok Yup. It sounds like a linking error when definition of the function is not provided - usually, when you forget to link the library. Missing declaration would yield `undefined symbol`. And it would be compiler error, not linker.

Comment: "undefined symbol" is typically a linker error as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usualy (if not always?) it's a linker error and it means missing definition. Compilation errors for missing declarations are similar to: "XXX was not declared in this scope."

Answer (score 4):

While it is technically compiler specific, "undefined reference" almost always means - as the error message states - that the definition is missing. I don't know of any compiler that would complain of an "undefined reference" when an unDECLARED symbol is being referenced.

Comment: Thanks, have verified it now, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem using the library with Qt.
the solution is to specify the path which leads to the `-lblob` file in the .pro file:

```
LIBS += -L/user/local/lib \
-lblob
```

Comment: This is a very special case, not an answer to the question whether "undefined reference" is caused by missing declarations or definitions.

Comment: @jogojapan From the rest of the answers anyone could get an idea of what's going on, it doesn't hurt to add a QT specific answer. Actually, it helps. Also, it is invisible but I suppose the most people who do find this useful are the same people who will not login and not upvote normally... Also, at times when people come here with a mind that usually don't seem to have the luxury of actually getting the picture at their disposal, letting then them have a chance to find the QT specific version might be what they need at the moment...